# Extending load cell wires

Tags: load-cell

I've Googled but didn't find an answer. Is it problematic to extend load cell wires? I would like to have the 4 cells under the 4 corners of something (since the object rests on those 4 corners), but we are talking about 2 meters by 2 meters. I can put the electronics in the center but want to put a load cell under each corner.

It's for this load cell:

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10245

Do I risk getting losses over that distance (approx 1.4 meters) that could render it useless?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest twisted pairs or STP wire to reduce susceptibility to noise.  with shld connected to combiner board only.  Is it serviceable underneath? I might not put it there.

Comment: No problem getting access there. Perfectly serviceable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that load cells are driven using a current source and read as a voltage, extending the drive wires (within reason) will not cause a reduction in current and extending the sense wires will not cause a reduction in voltage. so it should be fine to extend the wires.